# What are the names of yamanchuryas Discplies

Tags: sri-vaishnava

How many discplies were there with Yamachunarya and what is their names?

Comment: Please stop posting same question two times!

Comment: If you ask the same question again and again that won't solve your problem because all your subsequent questions will be closed as duplicate of the original question and duplicates are closed so can't be answered. So, there is no option for you other than to patiently wait for answers to your original question. Im not sure why are you so impatient? :)

Comment: I have not get answer for my pervious question that is why I have asked this question again please reply to my question

Comment: That's right but still you have to wait for answers to be posted on that original question. Asking the same question again will not help you fetch answers. @L.AravindKalaimani

Comment: I am requesting you to kindly reply to my question please help me

Comment: @L.AravindKalaimani There are so many questions in site without answers for 2 years. Please have patience...

Comment: @L.AravindKalaimani I have answered your other question on the disciples of Ramanuja... I am not aware of the answer to this question... Requesting you to kindly wait patiently until someone answers your question... If you post the same question twice, it is of no use... :)